# identifier " " is undefined

Tags: c++, opengl

I am coding a 3D opengl test application, I have a function set up like this:

```
Shader::Shader(const std::string& fileName)
{
    program = glCreateProgram();
    shaders[0] = CreateShader(LoadShader(fileName + ".vs"), GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    shaders[1] = CreateShader(LoadShader(fileName + ".fs"), GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    for (unsigned int i=0; i < NUM_SHADERS; i++)
        glAttachShader(program, shaders[1]);

    glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "position");

    glLinkProgram(program);
}
```

However when I try to declare `shaders[0] = CreateShader(LoadShader(fileName + ".vs"), GL_VERTEX SHADER);` I get the error: **identifier "shaders" is undefined**, how do I fix this?

Comment: Ask yourself : where `shaders` is defined and then show us how it is declared.

Comment: You have not declared an array of shaders.

Comment: *However when I try to declare* -- That line doesn't declare anything.  That line of code assigns the return value of `CreateShader` to something we (and the compiler) knows nothing about, i.e. `shaders[0]` and `shaders[1]`.

Comment: Is shaders[] a data member? or global varaible? What is its data type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `#include "shader.h"`. This will fix your issue.

I guess you are working on something similar to https://github.com/BennyQBD/ModernOpenGLTutorial. Here is the declaration for `m_shaders` https://github.com/BennyQBD/ModernOpenGLTutorial/blob/master/shader.h#L29. You are using `shaders` instead.

Comment: Yes that would be it;) - Will accept the answer as soon as I can

Comment: @JakeWickham So the only way to have answered your question is to take a random guess?  You should have provided those details as to what you're working with in the original question.

Comment: My answer wasn't a random guess. I have edited the answer for further details. But I agree with @PaulMcKenzie that you should include background details in the question.

Comment: @ShridharR.Kulkarni I am directing this to the OP.  It is a poor question to begin with if only 2 people have knowledge on where the code comes from.

Comment: I am new to answering questions here. Can you tell me what 'directing to OP' means? and have I answered something wrong?

Comment: @ShridharR.Kulkarni -- When a question is asked on SO, it should have all the requisite information so that the community knows how to answer the question.  How many of us knows about that site you linked to?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Yes I now understand your concern.