# can't remove last element of a vector using erase method

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector with these elements;

```
std::vector<int> v { 34,23 };
```

If I try to delete last element like this:

```
v.erase(v.begin()+1);
```

It gives me error.

any idea?

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: I hope you are using `#include <vector>`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem is with the deletion, rather you're not specifying what type your vector is holding... Try this

```
std::vector<int> v{ 34,23 };
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining that a bit more. What formatting?

Comment: When I compiled it with C++14, the code works fine even with space in between `v` and `{`. So we should wait for complete details in the question.

Comment: @ShridharR.Kulkarni please read the post - the answer clearly mentions that the OP didn't specify the TYPE of the vector. Which is `int` in this case and the OP forgot that. Spaces between `v` and `{` wouldn't matter, no matter the compiler.

Comment: @VadaPoché: OP mentioned `std::vector<int> v { 34,23 };` and answer mentions `std::vector<int> v{ 34,23 };` What is the difference between the two? Am I missing anything?

Comment: This was not the case. They did not specify the type, until you edited the question

Comment: @LiamT OP hadn't formatted the code correctly, so the `<int>` part wasn't rendered. But it was there.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I too think so. I don't remember adding the `<int>` part myself. The OP had int but it is not visible in edit history now. How come I don't know.

Comment: Anyways without even knowing what the error is one should not answer the question; alternatively should be added as a comment.

Comment: @ShridharR.Kulkarni if the OP hadn't bothered to properly format the question, and skipped out the `<int>` part, that wouldn't be the mistake of someone who answers the question based on the given information. I think you're being unfairly critical towards someone who tried to help.

Comment: This is hopefully my last comment on this answer. This is not being 'unfairly critical'. I had tried the same thing. Read the comments here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42591898/identifier-is-undefined/42591934#42591934. It is done to maintain the discipline on the forum and we should respect it. @VadaPoché Thanks for stating your views. I respect your & answerer's views too.